# Ограничение числа профилей пользователя

Tags: аутентификация

Стоит задача регистрировать пользователя в сервисе.
Но есть необходимость ограничения количества профилей у 1 пользователя,
Какие варианты вы можете предложить?
думал в сторону госуслуг но насколько понял они не дают апи обычным крестьянам.(или я заблуждаюсь?)
Можно было бы привязаться к СНИЛСу но в каком контексте его запросить у пользователя?
да и чтобы проверить принадлежность будет необходимы еще и паспортные, а это еще более усложняет вопрос.
Так вот есть у кого в практике подобные решения? мысли?

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях используют регистрацию по номеру телефона.

Comment: @stanislav-pechezerov у меня у самого 2 симкарты не вариант

Comment: не располагая базой для проведения централизованной проверки, вы вряд ли сможете гарантировать отсутствие повторных регистраций. Но вы можете их усложнить (требовать уникального почтового адреса, номера телефона, уникального корпоративного почтового адреса, и т.д). Предложу ещё такой вариант: Google Adsense, например, проверяет уникальность пользователей с помощью не электронного, а реального почтового адреса - туда направляется бумажное письмо с кодом. Но шанс воспользоваться чужим ящиком и регнуться повторно всегда останется.

Comment: @stanislav-pechezerov проверить СНИЛС по паспортным это не проблема
вокруг полно сервисов это предоставляющих
Такое вариант решения может быть, но тут слишком много нужно собрать мне кажется это отпугнет людей))

Comment: к слову, если у вас две симки, у меня может оказаться 200 сочетаний СНИЛС + паспорт + ИНН. Я думаю что купить такую информацию можно дешевле, чем сим-карту. Да и к тому же, всегда есть друзья и родственники, которые смогут помочь такие данные предоставить.